# Do McDonald's burgers resist decomposing because it harms any life form that ingests it?

Tags: nutrition, mcdonalds

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do McDonald's burgers have an unnaturally long lifespan?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7622/do-mcdonalds-burgers-have-an-unnaturally-long-lifespan)

Its a recurring theme over a few years.

http://www.occupymonsanto360.org/2012/02/06/why-mcdonalds-happy-meal-hamburgers-wont-decompose-the-real-story-behind-the-story/

---

The claim I want to examine is:

The burgers are so processed and impregnated with chemicals that makes it **repulsive to microbes and any other life forms**, and it is evidence that it is harmful to humans who consume it.

An impactful quote from the article:

> There is only one species on planet Earth that’s stupid enough to
>   think a McDonald’s hamburger is food. This species is suffering from
>   skyrocketing rates of diabetes, cancer, heart disease, dementia and
>   obesity.
>
> Source: http://www.occupymonsanto360.org (http://s.tt/18OaL)

---

A similar question: [Do McDonald's burgers have an unnaturally long lifespan?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7622/do-mcdonalds-burgers-have-an-unnaturally-long-lifespan)

I believe that it is a combination of high salt and quick dehydration, so only the high salt is problematic to humans.

Comment: Seems to be a very close match, closing.

Comment: Hmm it does mention: _Whether they are abnormal or unhealthy is an unrelated question_

Comment: *and it is evidence that it is harmful to humans who consume it.*. No it is not. Bacteria do not grow on honey either.

Comment: @nico, yes good honey has been recovered from the pyramids (or should I be skeptical about **that**?). But that claim kinda chills me.

Comment: @aitchnyu honey is a natural preservative. It's evolved that way as its intended purpose is for long term storage as food for bee colonies (long term as in months of course, not centuries).